# automcompleting material elements in vscode?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

[I'm going through this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43dVsSSo4lc&t=1095s) and when the author types in a custom material element vscode will autocomplete it when he hits return.

When I type and hit return this does not happen.  How do we enable this?

Comment: Do you see the Intellisense for the possible autocomplete options?

Comment: When I hit ctrl-space it just says "No suggestions"

Comment: Aha. Have you installed the type definitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you are already seeing suggestions**, there is a setting for accepting suggestions with `enter`, which we can enable in the user settings:

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "on",
```

**For TypeScript files**, if you are not seeing suggestions, you might need to install the packages that power the suggestions.

After running these commands...

```
npm init -y                            // init node project
npm install angular --save             // install angular 
npm install @types/angular --save-dev  // install angular types
npm install @angular/material --save   // install material
tsc --init                             // init TypeScript project
code .                                 // open VS Code
```

...this is what I see in my VS Code instance.

[image]

**For HTML files**, you might need to install and enable the [Angular Language Service VS Code Extension.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template)

[image]

Comment: I'm not even getting suggestions for completion of normal elements.  What do I need to install?

Comment: Where are you trying to see the intellisense? Is it in an HTML file or a TS file?

Comment: It's the app.component.html

Comment: Then you probably need the Angular Language Service. I will add details to the answer re: how to install that.

Comment: Cool - I'll check that out  - Thank you!

Comment: Hmmm - I added both the snippets and the language service, but still no autocomplete.  ...

Comment: Good to know. I can take another look later this week after work. Let me know though if you figure out the incantation to make it work or if not the command line steps that you take to set up your new Angular project. E.g. `ng init...`

Comment: @Ole Another question for you: at what point in the video (minutes:seconds) does show the auto-complete that you're trying to achieve? I am wondering because there are several forms of auto-complete and I am wondering exactly what parts of the auto-complete you're missing.